# Rotate a rect on canvas on user touch

Tags: android, android-canvas

I tried to check on web a lot about this but couldn't find any solution. I want to rotate a `rect` whenever a user drags it's `bottom-right` corner (pointed in the image) and the center of the `rotation` should be the same as center of the `rect`.

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to rotate the rect ??

Comment: what about the file i sent you in chat. Have you checked that file@ pskink

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate using canvas.

```
//Example


Path path = new Path();
path.addRect(166, 748, 314, 890, Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.save(); // first save the state of the canvas
canvas.rotate(45); // rotate it
canvas.drawPath(path, paint); // draw on it
canvas.restore(); // restore previous state (rotate it back)
```

[Android Implement onTouchListener on path objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841686/android-implement-ontouchlistener-on-path-objects)
check this link. You can `override onTouchEvent()`

Comment: it'll always rotate the canvas by 45 degree and i want to rotate it on user basis

Comment: Check Updated answer

Comment: but this will still rotate the canvas by 45 degree

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat you can change 45 to desired value like canvas.rotate(75); it will rotate 75 degrees

Comment: how to find that angle if user drags the bottom-right corner of the rect @WaleedAsim

Comment: Check link that i've given in answer. 
You first find the X and Y values using touchEvent and stored in some memory. only first time, for your purpose. next time, check if user X and Y values == to your saved X Y values then print toast to rotate angle

Answer (score 0):

general approach to determine rotation angle:

```
rotation center coordinates xc, yc

on touch (mouse) down: 
  check whether touch point is in grab region
  remember coordinates x0, y0
  set flag "InRotation"

on touch move:
  current coordinates x1, y1
  check if (they are in allowed region) and (InRotation is set)
    calculate rotation angle as
       alpha = Math.atan2((x1-xc)*(y0-yc) - (x0-xc)*(y1-yc), 
                            (x1-xc)*(x0-xc) + (y0-yc)*(y1-yc))
    redraw image using alpha angle

on touch up:
 clear InRotation flag
 make actions after rotation if needed
```

Note that you have to use rotation center coordinates in affine matrix calculation to properly draw rotated rectangle:

```
 canvas.save();
 canvas.rotate(alpha, xc, yc);
 canvas.drawRect(.....);
 canvas.restore();
```

Comment: what do you mean by ArcTan2 ?? is it atan2() ??

Comment: yes, it is atan2. And I don't know - it's result might be in radians (not degrees) in your language.

Comment: xc and yc is the center of rect ??

Comment: Yes, xc and yc is the center of rect, if you rotate rect about it''s center

Comment: ((x1-xc)*(y0-yc) - (x0-xc)*(y1-yc), 
                            (x1-xc)*(x0-xc) + (y0-xc)*(y1-yc))  are you sure this formula is correct ???.. plz check this one more time. i have a doubt in this

Comment: you said in your answer that  "redraw image using alpha angle" but this is not an image it's a rect . how to redraw it with rotation?

Comment: If initial rect has been drawn with angle `a0` (might be zero), new rectangle will be drawn with angle `a0 + alpha`

Comment: how to draw a rect with angle ??

Comment: I've added info.

Comment: I am getting the value of alpha between 0 and 1 , this is not working

Comment: what about radian??

Comment: See my first comment. Have you heard about angle measurement in radians?

Comment: yes @MBo , so i have to convert that angle in radians

Comment: atan2 result is in radians, canvas.rotate gets degrees, so you need to convert radians to degrees.

Comment: what if I don't want to rotate the whole canvas, i just want to rotate only rect because i'm moving the rect on touch inside the rect too. so after rotating the canvas i'm unable to move the rect in correct direction.

Comment: @pskink but in that example you are drawing a bitmap , and i'm using rect. can you tell me how to rotate a rect and then redraw it?? and you're also rotating the canvas